# Leaves of bounded genus

Tags: smooth-manifolds, foliations, surfaces

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a codimension one foliation in a closed $3$-manifold $M$. Does there exist an upper bound for the genus of the compact orientable leaves? That is, does there exist $G >0$ such that the genus of every compact orientable leaf is at most $G$?